# Yii2 url manager generates urls correctly but cannot parse named parameters

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing, yii-url-manager

I have a lot of rules like the this:

```
'/manager/stale-zwroty/zmien/<idDomain:\d+>' => '/owner/chat-texts/update',
```

Url is generated properly but when I try to enter the page `/manager/stale-zwroty/zmien/1` it is not able to read the `idDomain` parameter value.

I noticed that UrlRule instance corresponding to above rule has empty property `$this->placeholders`.

I have newest Yii version installed from composer. Previously it was working fine.

Here is the `var_dump` of the UrlRule instance result:

```
    object(yii\web\UrlRule)#59 (15) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(42) "/manager/stale-zwroty/zmien/<idDomain:\d+>"
  ["pattern"]=>
  string(50) "#^manager/stale-zwroty/zmien/(?P<ac4b8b691>\d+)$#u"
  ["host"]=>
  NULL
  ["route"]=>
  string(23) "owner/chat-texts/update"
  ["defaults"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["suffix"]=>
  NULL
  ["verb"]=>
  NULL
  ["mode"]=>
  NULL
  ["encodeParams"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["placeholders":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_template":"yii\web\UrlRule":private]=>
  string(39) "/manager/stale-zwroty/zmien/<idDomain>/"
  ["_routeRule":"yii\web\UrlRule":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_paramRules":"yii\web\UrlRule":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["idDomain"]=>
    string(8) "#^\d+$#u"
  }
  ["_routeParams":"yii\web\UrlRule":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_placeholders":"yii\web\UrlRule":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ac4b8b691"]=>
    string(8) "idDomain"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

Yii2 UrlManager gets the url-rules from cache. I deleted `runtime/cache` content and it's working now.